# Why do you only sometimes have to import extension methods?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1

Although this question is not Angular-2-specific, let's start with an example in Angular 2:

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

// ...

private foo() {
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
}
```

`toPromise()` is an extension method for the `Observable<Response>` returned by `this.http.get(url)`. You can only use it if you import `rxjs/add/operator/toPromise`, otherwise the compiler will complain. That file `toPromise.d.ts` has the following content:

```
import { toPromise } from '../../operator/toPromise';
declare module '../../Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        toPromise: typeof toPromise;
    }
}
```

However, for my own extension methods, no import is needed:

my-class.ts:

```
export class MyClass {}
```

my-class-extensions.ts:

```
import { MyClass } from "./my-class" ;

declare module "./my-class" {
    interface MyClass {
        myExtensionMethod;
    }
}
MyClass.prototype.myExtensionMethod = () => {};
```

(Alternatively, the last line can be removed and the file can be renamed to `my-class-extensions.d.ts`.)

my-consumer.ts:

```
import { MyClass } from "./my-class";
// No import necessary:
// import "./my-class-extensions";

// ...

foo(obj: MyClass) {
    obj.myExtensionMethod(); // Still fine!
}
```

So, why do you only sometimes have to import extension methods? And what can I do do make my extension methods "modular"?

Comment: They seem to be part of the same module `my-class`. Could it be that it wouldn't be the case if the module name was different?

Comment: You mean changing `declare module "./my-class"` to `declare module "./my-class-extensions"`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Although I wasn't sure if you could do that.

Comment: In that case, the extension won't work at all. The compiler will not recognize `myExtensionMethod` as member of `MyClass`.

Comment: To be more precise: It will recognize `myExtensionMethod` as a member of a synonymous but different class `MyClass`.

Comment: Are you sure that `toPromise.d.ts` has the code that you've pasted above. Looking at this page it looks like it's not declaring a module, but exporting a function: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/toPromise.ts. One more link suggests the same: https://github.com/JonatanSCS/Angular-2-Tutorial/blob/master/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, this works:

```
// my-class.ts
export class MyClass {
    firstMethod = (): void => {
        console.log("First method")
    } 
}

// my-class.extended.ts
import { MyClass as MyClassBase } from './my-class'

class MyClassExtended extends MyClassBase {
    secondMethod = (): void => {
        console.log("Second method")
    }
}
export { MyClassExtended as MyClass }

// index.ts
import { MyClass } from './my-class.extended'

let myClassInstance = new MyClass()
myClassInstance.secondMethod()

// Outputs "Second method"
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this approach, secondMethod would not be termed an extension method.